# System.StringException: Invalid id on class test

Tags: rest-api

I'am trying to create api call using Postman and SF and i'm getting an error message when I try to create contracts.

message = System.StringException: Invalid id

code
Class is below:

```
@HttpPost
global static String createNewContract() {
    RestRequest request = RestContext.request;
    Map<String, Object> requestResult = (Map<String, Object>) JSON.deserializeUntyped(request.requestBody.toString());
    List<Object> contracts = (List<Object>) requestResult.get('records');
    List<Contract> contractsToInsert = new List<Contract>();
    
    for (Object contractObject : contracts) {
        Map<String, Object> parsedContract = (Map<String, Object>) contractObject;
        Contract thisContract = new Contract(
               Name = (String) parsedContract.get('Name'),
                Status =  (String) parsedContract.get('Status'),
                AccountId =  (String) parsedContract.get('AccountId'),
                StartDate = Date.valueOf((String) parsedContract.get('StartDate')),
                ContractTerm = Integer.valueOf((String) parsedContract.get('ContractTerm'))
        );
        contractsToInsert.add(thisContract);
    }
    Database.upsert(contractsToInsert, Contract.Id, true);
    
    Map<String, String> stringMap = new Map<String, String>();
    for (Contract contract : contractsToInsert) {
        if (contract.Id != null) {
            stringMap.put(contract.Id, contract.Name);
        }
    }
    return JSON.serializePretty(stringMap);
}
```

Class Test is :

```
@isTest
static void testCreateContract() {
 
    RestRequest request = new RestRequest();
    request.requestUri ='https://**********-ed.develop.lightning.force.com//services/apexrest/Contact/';
    request.httpMethod = 'POST';
    RestContext.request = request;        
    request.requestBody = Blob.valueOf('{"records" : [{"attributes" : {"type" : "Contract"},"Name": "ContractName-1","AccountId": "0010600002Cw3Z3AAJ","Status": "Draft","StartDate": "2024-02-01","ContractTerm": "6"}]}');        
    Test.startTest();
    Id thisContractId = ContractService.createNewContract();
    Contract thisContract = [SELECT Id, Name, StartDate, ContractTerm, Status FROM Contract WHERE Id =:thisContractId];
    Test.stopTest();
    
    // Check contract is created
    System.assertEquals(thisContract.ContractTerm, 6);
    System.assertEquals(thisContract.Status, 'Draft');
    System.assertEquals(thisContract.Name, 'ContractName-1');
    System.assert(thisContract.Id != null);
}
```

Any idea on what I'm doing wrong please ?

Answer (score 1):

```
Id thisContractId = ContractService.createNewContract();
```

fails because you're returning a JSON body, not an individual Id. You'd instead want to do something like:

```
String jsonResponse = ContractService.createNewContract();
Map<String, String> results = (Map<String, String>)JSON.deserialize(jsonResponse, Map<String, String>.class);
Id theContractId = new List<String>(results.keySet())[0];
```

Note that you can't use a hard-coded ID in unit tests regarding most data because of the [Isolation of Test Data from Organization Data in Unit Tests](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_testing_data_access.htm). You need to create an account in the unit test.